# Need to make vlookup with variable lookup sheet

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

I am creating a vlookup that references the previous sheet for the lookup values. I tried `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC1,Sheets(Sheets.Count - 1)!R1C1:R600C14,11,FALSE)"` but I am getting an "Application or Object defined error". I am sure there is a way to do this, but am struggling to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is untested, but I think your formula is being very literal with the way you've written it.  Try something like this:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC1,'" & _
    Sheets(Sheets.Count - 1).Name & "'!R1C1:R600C14,11,FALSE)"
```

Comment: I had tried this, but without the .Name. When I try your version, as soon as the line runs, it opens a dialog window to select a file. The window is titled "Update Values: 15". I have no idea what this is or how that code made it happen.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think that line of code is causing that... not that it's impossible, but I don't see how it could.  Can you put a break point on this one line and run it in debug mode to see what it does to the active cell?  I went ahead and ran it on a test spreadsheet, just to see what would happen, and I did have success.

Comment: I created a sub that has nothing but that line of code and stepped through it. It immediately opens up that dialog when it runs that line. I copied and pasted it from your answer. It does put the code in the cell and the formula looks correct except for one thing. The name of each tab is the date in the format 9-24-15. The macro wrote the formula as =VLOOKUP($A13,9-24-'15'!$A$1:$N$600,11,FALSE) Notice the quotes around the 15, a correct formula would have the quotes around the whole date. It results in a #REF error.

Comment: Regarding the sheet name "9-24-15," yes, you're right.  If the sheet name begins with a number or perhaps even has a space, it probably needs single quotes around it for the formula to work.  I have attempted to update the answer to include the single quotes, which should be harmless if not needed.  Regarding the dialog box...  as Vizzini from The Princess Bride would say, "Inconceivable!"  My only thought is maybe there is a worksheet_change event on one of the sheets that is firing with that dialog box?  Did you run this on a clean worksheet also?

Comment: Ok, so it looks like it is the date thing causing the issues, and I am going to assume it is the dashes in particular. If I just use a word, the code works fine. I assume the dialog window is because the program can't find the tab it thinks it is looking for so it wants me to browse to it. So does anyone have any idea how to get around the crazy thing that is happening with the dashes? Does Excel VBA not recognize the whole name of a tab if it includes a dash?

Comment: The single quote addition worked for my purposes. It is just kind of weird how that behaved. Thanks.

Comment: You may want to look at the `CodeName` property instead of `Name`.  It retains the original name of the worksheet, such as Sheet1, Sheet2, etc, even after you give it a different cosmetic label.  Either way, I'm glad you got it working.  That is really interesting about the dialog box.  I never would have expected that behavior, but I tested it on my end and actually got the same result -- who knew.